# Error when using AUC package in R

Tags: r, auc

We use the AUC package in R to evaluate the model prediction.

Sometimes, we faced the error like below:

```
    > plot(roc(pred, yTEST))
    > auc(roc(pred, yTEST)) 
    Error in rank(prob) : argument "prob" is missing, with no default
```

Could anyone let us know where the error comes from ? Note that: the problem did not occur frequently. For example: we ran 10 models and it happened to 3-4 models.

Comment: We need to see more code - a MWE - for us to help more

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you might have loaded glmnet after AUC (glmnet also has a auc function). Just used AUC:: before the function.